# Magento list associated simple products as configurable product

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I’m gonna tell my problem with an example.

I have a configurable product. Name is: “test” 
And I created 4 simple products with different size. They are associated. 
Test-Small 
Test-Medium 
Test-Large 
Test-XLarge

I’m getting all products with this code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
```

I want to these 4 products as one. With all size attributes. As one.

If I’m gonna add “size=small” attribute to code, “test” will be returned product. 
If I’m gonna add “size=medium” attribute to code “test” will be returnded again. 
If I’m gonna add “size=large” attribute to code “test” will be returnded again. 
If I’m gonna add “size=xlarge” attribute to code “test” will be returnded again.

How can I do that? Maybe I need advanced sql, let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question but you might be able to filter the collection with the type attribute. eg type_id='configurable' or type_id='simple'.

```
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));
```

**EDIT following comments below

So, then, I think what you want to do is run the collection as-is, then from the simple product, find out what its configurable is using the function

$productParentId = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($simpleProductId);

The function will return an array and you may need additional logic to deduce which configurable but I expect most stores operate with only one configurable product per simple product. I use $productParentId[0] to identify the configurable products in my store.

Comment: I want to apply "size" attribute to configurable product. But as you know it doesnt have. (in this example)

So If I'm gonna apply size attribute to asssociated simple products, I want to get return configurable product. I dont know how can I explain this. @Malachy